# Sugar CRM api test with Postman

Tags: rest, api, postman, sugarcrm

I am new to Sugar CRM ...and got a task to test the Rest api of sugar crm. I got an url , username ,password where i can login and view the page and it is working well. But while i am testing it with Postman for JSON response it is not giving me any response. Can anyone suggest me the right way to test the api...with an example or i am making the wrong url as request??

Here is document how to create the url
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/REST/

And there is another problem of version. As i only got url to login how can i get the sugar version from webpage ??

Comment: `As i only got url to login how can i get the sugar version from webpage ??`
Just fetch the file `/sugar_version.json` from Sugar. It tells you the version and flavor of Sugar in the convenient JSON format and doesn't require any login.

Answer (score 1):

Use this lovely feature of Postman
Post the login info:
POST /rest/v10/oauth2/token
BODY

```
{
  "grant_type": "password",
  "client_id": "...",
  "client_secret": "",
  "username": "....",
  "password": "....",
  "platform": "...."
}
```

and in TESTS tab:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("OAuth-Token", jsonData.access_token);
```

now you have the token in your environment and you can use it in the header of other requests:

[image: In your headers]

Answer (score 0):

Hello If you want to use Postman to see your result of API , Following are the steps:

1. You have to generate a access token for you sugar crm , so you have to write a code which will accept user name  password and and generate the access code .
   You have to hit that api URL using postman which will generate the access token .

   [Check this link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Integration/Web_Services/v10/)
2. Copy that access token in another tab of Postman , select AUth type and insert access token to it.
   then submit you URL you will get the result in Postman

[Link 2](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/02/28/sugarcrm-cookbook1/)